# Receive transformation map function to send into `List<>.mapNotNull()`

Tags: kotlin, higher-order-functions

Im trying to write a function like `transform` that receives a function that will be used inside of mapNotNull but I cant find a way to do it.

Example

```
val items: List<String?> = listOf(null, "cosa")

fun transform(transformer: (String) -> String?) {
    items.mapNotNull(transformer) // <-------------------------------------- THIS DOES NOT COMPILE
}

fun main() {
    val items: List<String?> = listOf(null, "cosa")

    val transformer: (String) -> String? = {
        null    
    }

    val map = transform(transformer)

    print(map)

}
```

You can check how this works here: [play.kotlinlang](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

How can I declare the parameter of `fun transform` to be able to pass it inside of the `mapNotNull` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mapNotNull` function is defined as:

```
public inline fun <T, R : Any> Iterable<T>.mapNotNull(transform: (T) -> R?): List<R>
```

in other words, the type of the parameter to the `transform` lambda is `T`, where `T` is the type of the `Iterable` being operated on. In your case, your iterable is a `List` of type `String?`.

Therefore, you need to declare your transformer as type `(String?) -> String?`, and only the non-null results of that transform will be included in the result.

To update the code you supplied on play.kotlinlang, with a few additional modifications to make the type declarations a bit more idiomatic -- note, I've left the code mostly as-is, despite the odd use of the additional `transform` function:

```
val items = listOf<String?>(null, "cosa")

fun transform (transformer: (String?) -> String?): List<String> {
    return items.mapNotNull(transformer)
}

fun main() {
    val items = listOf<String?>(null, "cosa")

    val transformer: (String?) -> String? = {
        // this of course means the output of transform will always be empty
        null    
    }

    val map = transform(transformer)

    print(map)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of nullable strings.

`mapNotNull` applies the transform function to an each element in a list and then checks if the result of this functions is null. So in this case, it passes a nullable string in the `transformer` function, and that function definitely cannot be of `(String) -> String?` type because the parameter here is a non-nullable string.

You should either declare the transformer function as `(String?) -> String?`, or remove nulls from list before calling `mapNotNull`:

```
items.filterNotNull().mapNotNull(transformer)
```

Another option is to wrap `transformer` into a lambda function before passing it to `mapNotNull` and handle null elements there, for example:

```
items.mapNotNull { e -> e?.let(transformer) }
```

this applies `transformer` function to an element only if it is not null.